# Postgres "group by" on aggregate function(s)

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have a query that returns an array of IDs which I then sort into order using a custom function as follows:-

```
SELECT array_sort(my_array) as sort FROM table
```

This will return:-

```
{19,21,24,48}
{19,21,24}
{19,21}
{19}
{16,12,13}
{16,12}
...
```

I want to pick the longest array with distinct first elements, so from the list above I would get:-

```
{19,21,24,48} and {16,12,13}
```

How can I achieve this, I tried pulling out the first element as a separate item, sorting by length and attempting to group as follows:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT (array_sort(path))[1] as first, array_length(path,1) as plen, array_sort(path) as members FROM table GROUP BY first,plen,members ORDER BY plen DESC
```

This does not work and simply orders the list

Comment: Consider rephrasing. It's not clear at all what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`distinct on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) clause:

```
with cte as (
  select
      array_length(members,1) as plen,
      members[1] as first,
      members
  from (select array_sort(path) as members from table) as a
)
select distinct on (first)
    members
from cte
order by first, plen desc
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6ffe6/2)</kbd>**